Range of Vector Measure Closed?
Lyapunov's theorem shows that the range of a finite-dimensional non-atomic vector measure is closed and compact. What if we do not assume the vector measure is non-atomic? Is the range still necessarily closed? (Obviously convexity may fail.)
If it e.g. a Borel measure on a topological space then the answer is yes, as in such a case we can remove a countable set of atoms $x_1,x_2,x_3,\ldots$ it's easy to show that range of the purely atomic part is closed, and then to apply Lyapunov's theorem to the non-atomic part.
But in stranger spaces...?

It does not matter what the $\sigma$-algebra is. Just partition the measurable space into the disjoint union of at most countably many atoms and a nonatomic subspace.

OK, I see, but the difference is is that the atoms needn't be single points, rather more general sets. Thnx.
